# Чем и как можно проверить хостинг?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, хостинг

Я выбираю себе хостинг. Не vds/vps, а так называемый облачный (виртуальный) хостинг. Многие хостинг провайдеры предоставляют тестовый период: 3-30 дней. Подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь методы проверки хостинга? Может быть вы знаете какие-нибудь бенчмарки?

http://www.webhostingspeedtest.com/test-your-web-hosting.php
Не работает (или просто не удалось завести)

https://www.webhosting-performance.com
Сейчас юзаю

Comment: А что вы хотите проверить? Количество попугаев доступное в данный отрезок времени?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/99318/)...но сдесь проверка "сайта" в основном...а о хостинге и так все известо....характеристики и все такое